# Initialize data for Query Types Ef core 2.1

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I'm using InMemory database to test my repository logic. But I have this report database view model.

```
public DbQuery<DBVIEWMODEL> Reports { get; set; }
```

The thing is, I can't initialize it with dummy data for my unit test. There is no such thing like, Add, AddRange...

So my question; am I allowed to initialize this Query type? Or Query type is not meant for unit test?

FYI:

I can do my unit test, if I change `DbQuery<>` to `DbSet<>` and set a dummy Id in my view using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is no.
A `DbSet` is a set of data that can be edited, added or deleted. But `DbQuery` represents a query OVER a set of data, there are no C_UD operation (Create, Update, Delete).